# Assigning multiple return variables, but one at a time?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, iteration, nltk

I am trying to parse some data and format using nltk, but I can't seem to assign multiple returns to multiple variables over a function iteration (see def preprocess function below.) I tried rewriting my code, which usually leads to a big debug, but it seems I am hitting my head against a Python wall that is intentionally there.

```
def get_7text():
    with open('parsed_text/Larrys Pizza & Sports Parlor_text.csv','r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        dict = [row for row in reader]
    file.close()

    my_dict = [l[0] for l in dict]
    text= my_dict[0]
    new_dict=ast.literal_eval(text)
    for k,v in new_dict.items():
        exec(k + '=v')  
    return Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday

def preprocess():
    for day in Days:
        day = str(day)
        day = sent_tokenize(day)
        day = [word_tokenize(s.lower()) for s in day]
        day = [pos_tag(s) for s in day]
        return day

#code here 
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday = get_7text()
Days=[Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday]
Days=preprocess()
```

Get7text() returns 7 strings which I can successfully assign. I used to first have it return a dictionary of 7 keys, but formatting was annoying for POS tagging, etc. for NLTK.

The problem is this. Whenever I run preprocess, the program only keeps the 1st item in the list and forgets the other 6. I am trying to force the function to assign each returned output to a list of variables called Days, but to no avail. I also noticed that AFTER Days=preprocess(), Days loses all but the first element (Tuesday through Sunday are empty list of 1 string). However, Days[3] or Days[5] prints the expected data correctly.

I'm expecting there's a better method of representation out there. There are no posts online mentioning it, and it seemed like a sketchy thing to do anyway.

Comment: Why `return day`? It will return after processing first element since it's in the for loop.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever python sees 'return' it says, "Oh, return, you must be done with your code. I'll stop the function now." As such, it stops after the first iteration. Instead, what you should do is :

```
    def preprocess():
        retList = []
        for day in Days:
            day = str(day)
            day = sent_tokenize(day)
            day = [word_tokenize(s.lower()) for s in day]
            day = [pos_tag(s) for s in day]
            retList.append(day)
       return (retList)
```

Naturally, if this doesn't work, then I missed something and we're both at a loss.

Comment: Very straightforward tip. Thanks for solving!

Comment: Don't mind if I steal the quote, but this is going to be my quote when teaching functions from now on: `"Oh, return, you must be done with your code. I'll stop the function now."` ;P

Comment: BTW, use this idiom instead: `tagged_day = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) for sent in sent_tokenize(day.lower())]`